# Webmatrix Layout -- Inserting into head?

Tags: layout, razor, webmatrix

I've created a web site using Asp.Net and the Razor view engine (which is the same as using WebMatrix).  Up to now, I've been using SQL to query databases directly, but now I have a page which needs to query a WCF service that returns XML (getting that to return JSON or ODATA maybe is for a separate question).

On doing this, I was looking at the best way to do this, and it seems that jQuery may be the answer (unless you have other thoughts).

The problem is I'm using SiteLayout using the Layout="~/SiteLayout.cshtml" and I can't work out how to override or insert extra information specific to this page into the head tag that is in the SiteLayout, such as the script I need to add?

I'm pretty sure I'm thinking about this wrong, so if anyone has the answer to point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You mentioned something about jQuery. I would personally recommend using TypeScript: http://www.typescriptlang.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can to define a `Head` section in the child pages:

```
@section Head {
    <script> ... </script>
}
```

You can then call `RenderSection("Head")` in the `<head>` in the layout page to render this section.
You may want to pass `, required: false`.

For more information, see [ScottGu's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)

Comment: Excellent, thanks... Not sure why I couldn't find that in any docs etc.  Quite new, so probably my search terms were duff... Thanks again.