# Per Page CSS With ASP.NET Web Pages

Tags: css, asp.net-webpages

I am looking to split my css into sections with my asp.net web pages project. I have a layout css file that is linked in the _siteLayout.cshtml file that covers all the css related to the layout but not anything in the @renderBody()

What I would like to do is have one css file per partial page. As an example for the default.cshtml file I would like it to have its own css file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe my structuring of the question was wrong, but this answer is what I was looking for.

[Webmatrix Layout -- Inserting into head?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569182/webmatrix-layout-inserting-into-head)

Comment: Yes, this is how I achieved the same result. Thanks for spreading it.